# Click and drag not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

[Check this site.](http://unirazz.com/kb/html/movie.html)

It's working fine in all browsers but when I run this in iPhone Safari, it does not work correctly. It's just a JavaScript code that finds click and drag event. Using click and drag I am changing images. Please click and drag images.

I need some special code for making this work in iPhone Safari.

Comment: Makes sense. You can't *click* to drag stuff on an iPhone.

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._ **The link above is broken**, and the question is too broad anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile webkit doesn't use mousedown/mouseup events that are the basis for conventional web drag and drop.  Instead, mobile webkit uses touch events.

Have a look at this blog post for details:

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/